# SQL: REPLACE INTO statement can be combined with a case?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a replace into DB call, but I only want it to execute if the supplied printerid# is greater then the database stored printerid#.

Here is my example code which hopefully makes sense of this

```
unitid = 2382;
printerid = 9826;

REPLACE INTO devices (unitid, printerid)
VALUES ('"+ unitid +"', '"+ printerid +"')
WHILE '"+printerid+"' > devices.printerid
```

So for example, if the devices database already has an entry for unitid 2382 that has a printer ID of 9999, then the SQL call should do nothing, but if it had a printer ID of 8888 it would replace it with my new printer ID of 9826.

The above listed SQL code doesn't work though obviously. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` assuming you have a primary/unique key on `unitid`:

```
INSERT INTO devices (unitid, printerid)
VALUES ('"+ unitid +"', '"+ printerid +"')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE devices
SET unitid = '"+ unitid +"', printerid = '"+ printerid +"'
WHERE unitid = '"+ unitid +"' AND printerid < '"+ printerid +"'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), you can use `replace into ... select`.  That would allow you to verify that the new `printerid` is greater than the old one with a subquery:

```
replace into devices 
        (unitid, printerid) 
select  '"+ unitid +"'
,       '"+ printerid +"'
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    devices
        where   unitid = '"+ unitid +"'
                and printerid >= '"+printerid+"'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) you can use VALUES() to reference the values from the attempted insert -

```
INSERT INTO
    devices (unitid, printerid)
    VALUES (2382, 9826)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    printerid = IF(VALUES(printerid) > printerid, VALUES(printerid), printerid)
```